# Rails 4: found 1 results, but was looking for 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I get above error for following query.

```
 @customer= Customer.find(params[:id], :include => [:addresses, :temporary_address], :conditions => ["customer_no= ?", current_user.customer_no])
```

I think I am messing up with syntax. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to do a ID based lookup, but then add conditions to it?
Either way if you want more than one result, don't do a `find(id)` query, use `where()`

```
@customer = Customer.where(:customer_no => current_user.customer_no).include([:addresses, :temporary_address])
```

If you still want to run with your original query, do this:

```
@customer = Customer.find_by(:id => params[:id], :customer_no => current_user.customer_no).include([:addresses, :temporary_address])
```

And yes you are using a (very) old ActiveRecord syntax here :)

Comment: Well, your code didn't work quite okay. Had to tweek a little.
@customer = Customer..includes([:addresses, :temporary_address]).find_by(:id => params[:id], :customer_no => current_user.customer_no)

Comment: You are correct, includes needs to be before find_by as the latter already returns a record, not a relation object. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old ActiveRecord query interface syntax. Are you upgrading an old Rails application to Rails 4? Try the newer syntax:

```
@customer = Customer.includes(:addresses, :temporary_address).where("customer_no = ?", current_user.customer_no).find(params[:id])
```